# Get startActivityForResult result in static function

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm working from Unity and want to get the result of a file picking activity. Since I can't start activities from Unity itself, I created an "intermediant" static class called EclipseIntegration:

```
package com.Unity3D.EclipseIntegration;

public class EclipseIntegration {

    public static String selectedPath = "really ";

      public static void Launch(Activity activity) {
        Intent target = new Intent(activity, MyActivity.class);
        activity.startActivity(target); 
      }
}
```

activity is the Activity Unity is currently running in.

MyActivity is meant to start the real activity, because I need something that inherits from Activity to get the onActivityResult event:

```
package com.Unity3D.EclipseIntegration;

public class MyActivity extends Activity{

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {         
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
           Launch();
       }

      public void Launch() {
        Intent target = FileUtils.createGetContentIntent();
        Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(target, "Select a movie");
        startActivityForResult(intent); 
      }

      @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 128:   
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {  
                    final Uri uri = data.getData();
                    File file = FileUtils.getFile(uri);
                    EclipseIntegration.selectedPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
                }
                else EclipseIntegration.selectedPath = "";
                finish();
        }
    }     
}
```

but nothing happens. If I start the final activity directly in the static class like this :
activity.startActivity(intent); it works though, so I suppose I made some error while setting up the MyActivity? Despite trying this for 2 days now I couldn't find it though, so any nudge in the right direction would be very appreciated :)

Thanks,
kiriri

Comment: may be it has to do with the life of MyActivity instance? May be it's garbage collected before receiving the result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
public void Launch() {
            Intent target = FileUtils.createGetContentIntent();
            Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(target, "Select a movie");
            startActivityForResult(intent,128); 
          }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I missed that, but unfortunately it didn't help either. If it's not obvious to someone experienced like you then it's probably something Unity does. I had hoped there was some blatant problem with my action though :D